# Как сделать многопользовательскую информационную систему?

Tags: база-данных, postgresql

На предприятии создаётся информационная система сопровождения производства, которая состоит из базы данных (PostgreSQL) и программного обеспечения автоматизированных рабочих мест. Какой подход лучше выбрать для организации коллективного доступа?

Варианты:

1. Для каждого пользователя создать учетную запись внутри СУБД. Таким образом, СУБД проверяет имя и пароль, контролирует права доступа. Но в этом случае непонятно, как связать имя пользователя в СУБД с его реальными данными (ФИО, ...). Можно ли создавать внешний ключ в системную таблицу?
2. Создать таблицу "Пользователи", в которой хранить имена пользователей, ФИО, хеш пароля; создать дополнительную таблицу "Права", имеющую внешний ключ в таблицу "Пользователи". Но в этом случае усложняется контроль за уровнем доступа.
3. Ваш вариант.

Какие идеи?

UPD1. Нет, не две системы. Одна база данных, доступ к которой обеспечивается множеством приложений; каждое приложение для своего АРМ. Вопрос относится исключительно к построению модели данных, а информация об АРМ дана для полноты картины. Я хочу узнать, какие есть типовые схемы работы с пользователями и их правами, которые применяются на практике. Предложил свои мысли по этому поводу. Верны ли они? Почему?

UPD2. Значит, первый вариант. Правильно ли я понимаю, что в этом случае нужно создавать внешний ключ в таблицу [pg_authid](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/catalog-pg-authid.html)? Допустимо ли это в рабочих проектах?

UPD3. [Здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15067770/postgresql-foreign-key-to-role-oid) пишут, что добавлять внешние ключи, ссылающиеся на системные таблицы, нельзя.

Comment: Чуть побольше подробностей плиз. Нужно объединить две системы? У каждой системы своя БД, как я понял? У обоих систем PostgreSQL?

Comment: У вас нет выбора. Вам **придётся** контролировать доступ на уровне базы, потому что **другого общего звена для контроля просто нет**, а доверять защищённости клиентского ПО ненадёжно.

Comment: @D-side, добавил информацию в вопрос.

Comment: Не знаком с PostgreSQL, но осмелюсь предположить - вы говорите про пользователей что принадлежат самой базе и про пользователей что присутствуют в базе приложения. Взаимодействие с базой осуществляется с помощью запрос-ответ или держится активное соединение?

Comment: @borodatych, именно так. Держится активное соединение.

Answer (score 0):

Я считаю, что создавать системных пользователей для управления каким либо приложением не правильно.

У системных пользователей своя роль - доступ именно к БД и работе с/над ней, а не внутри.

Ну или хотя бы не в таких масштабах, а группами - к пр, южный округ имеет доступ в таблицам с префиксом "southDistrict_", и по направлюющей...

Логин/пароль на подключения к БД прописываются в настройках программы, а далее авторизация уже по логину паролю самого пользователя.

Для пущей безопастности, доступ дать только на выполнения процедур и функций, чтение видов, работу триггеров.

Доступ на выполнения можно проверять прямо в процедуре или функции.
Это касаемо активного соединения...

Ввиду популярности сервисов, я бы лучше организовал все это в виде сервиса.
Это даст некую гибкость при выборе написания клиентских частей - мобильных к примеру.

Comment: borodatych, спасибо за ответ, но я уже принял вариант, одобренный D-side. Как он справедливо отметил, другого общего звена для контроля нет. А если использовать сервисы как общее звено, то придётся городить общую серверную часть.